# How to generate dynamic form with a child component

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I am implementing a dynamic form, which can be created through a "add" button.
this dynamic form is also a component, we called child component.

the parent component looks just like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let station of stationFormData.controls; let stationFormIndex = index"
         class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <div [formGroup]="station">
          <app-charge-station-modification-contact [contacts]="stations[stationFormIndex]?.contact"[form]="station"></app-charge-station-modification-contact>
 </div>
<button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Add New Station" (click)="addNewStation()">
      <mat-icon class="add-button-enabled-color">add</mat-icon>
    </button>
          
</div>
```

and this `addNewStation` funtion looks like this:

```
public addNewStation(): void {
    console.log(this.stations);
    this.stationFormData.push(this.fb.group({
      contact: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
        name: { value: '', disabled: false },
      })]),
      })]),
      
    }));
  }
```

so this method will create a new form called contact.

this contact is a child component.

looks like this:

```
<div fxLayout="row" class="parameterWrapper">
  <div class="parameterLabel">contact</div>
    <div *ngFor="let contactForm of contactFormData.controls; let contactFormIndex = index"
       class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <div [formGroup]="contactForm">
      <div fxLayout="row" class="parameterWrapper">
        <div class="parameterLabelStep">name</div>
        <label>
          <input class="parameterInput" type="text" formControlName="name"
                 [disabled]="contactForm.controls.name.disabled"
                 [value]="contactForm.controls.name">
        </label>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my problem is, I dont know, how to implement a dynamic form which is generated by a child component.

I have tried several times, but I got alway errors.

any solutions?

Comment: is the child form a new form altogether, or just a formarray or formgroup of the parent?

Comment: this child form will be used also after ngInit, it can also be used for a new form.